# Alerting users in danger of being flagged for serial voting

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, serial-voting

### EDIT:

I've been recieving quite a bit of criticism over this question so I have edited it to hopefully reach a compromise that everyone can agree upon.

While I disagree that imposing a downvote limit from one person to another would negatively impact the SE voting system, I understand that imposing such a limit is not an answer that will be agreed upon and thus is not the proper solution.

> For this reason I propose an alternate solution that does not impose any limits whatsoever.  **Instead** of imposing limits, a simple notification system to let a user know when they are in danger of being flagged by the automated system for serial down/upvoting could be put in place.

Adding this alert would effectively discourage people who actually intend to "serial down/upvote."  I'm sure most people who are serial voters are unaware that a system is in place to stop it, and just notifying them that this system exists would be enough to discourage many of them.

**To address another point made:**

This would also be very helpful to those who run into a user who frequently asks bad questions.  As noted in a previous comment on Monica Cellio's response to this question, the automated system frequently fails when a user spams multiple bad questions and the downvotes are falsely detected as being "serial downvotes." ([See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199418/fix-serial-downvoting-reversal-to-not-apply-to-users-spamming-site-front-page-wi))

Alerting users that their votes may be reversed by the automated system if they do too many would relieve some of that problem. (Obviously it would not fix the problem, the system is inherently broken when dealing with situations like these, but a true solution to that issue should be left for another proposal).

***The original question below is kept only for consistency and so all of the responses make sense.  All future votes on this question should reflect the edit and not the original post.***

---

### ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I've asked numerous questions on Stack Overflow.  Just recently I began to notice that almost every new question I ask always gets one downvote, regardless of the quality of the question.

Obviously I don't know who is downvoting my questions, or even if it is the same person each time; but it at least begs the question . . . Could there be someone out there purposely downvoting my questions because of a personal vendetta?

Not that this kind of rivalry happens frequently, but people have it out for each other in the comments section all the time so I wouldn't be surprised if some rivalries form.

I think it would be a good idea to limit how many times one user can downvote another user.  (Obviously the limit would be reasonable, for example you may be only allowed to downvote another user's questions and/or responses 10 times in one month.)

Even if such a limit were imposed and you find that you reach this limit; if the user you wish to downvote truly has bad questions all the time, they will get enough downvotes from other users anyways.

**Chances are if a user reaches this limit they are probably trying to abuse the voting system anyways.  If a user frequently reaches this limit it would be a useful indication to look into them for potential serial downvoting.**

To any naysayers to this question saying it would be a bad idea because it encourages users to ask bad questions... Think about it realistically.  **Would you frequently reach this limit..?** I highly doubt it.  And if you would frequently reach this limit, maybe you should stop for a minute and question your voting habits.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me (possibly answers all your questions too)

Comment: If you suspect that a single user is targeting you with downvotes, you can flag a post and ask a mod to look into it for you. We can't see who cast votes, but we have some tools to detect this kind of thing at a higher level, and we can escalate to SE team if necessary. This is the kind of thing that calls for case-by-case evaluation, not a broad downvote limit.

Comment: @ff524 but don't let that suspicion only be based on looking at your own profile. On some tags on SO you pick up a down vote quickly, so a flag would only fly if the users watching that tag up vote new posts all day long, except for this particular user. If they down vote all posts the flag would be declined, this OP is still targeted by a couple of users but nothing will change. And I see enough comments pointing out stuff/asking for clarification so I doubt your advice will turn into success for this particular case.

Comment: Also, and since it's your first time on meta, please note that down votes here don't indicate quality, but legitimate disagreement.

Comment: This would prevent those that actually care about site standards from expressing that view. It means low quality can beat curation by just increasing the amount of crap they spew out.  Which is extremely destructive for the site in question.

Comment: Afaik, this is automatically handled. I disagreed with someone's answer once, and ended up losing a few hundred Rep due to him going over a ton of my q/a, and downvoting them all. It was fixed automatically the next day.

Answer (score 6):

> I think it would be a good idea to limit how many times one user can downvote another user.

No. Please no. A lot of people are arguing that there aren't enough downvotes happening, and the negative rep of downvote(s) can't and sometimes doesn't remove the rep of pity upvotes. <sup>1</sup> [There are scripts that will detect serial-voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). [<strike>You can also run a reputation recalc on demand</strike>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc?answertab=active#tab-top). Rep recalculations are consistently being run these days. That's already covered.

With restricting downvotes, you're also stopping users that qualify for evaluating the bad quality of some questions <sup>2</sup>, among a small percentage of users who are the real culprits. *And* stopping some users from getting the bans they deserve for their low-quality contributions.

**So it's a no.**

---

1: which triggered [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased?s=2|0.0000) That failed though. :/

2: I *have* seen "leeches" that tend to ask low quality questions all the time. Knowingly, *or* unknowingly, you're stopping their bad posts from getting downvotes.

Comment: Pretty sure manual rep recalc has gone the way of the dodo; [recalcs happen pretty continuously these days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes).

Comment: Realistically this would not stop "leeches" from getting the downvotes they deserve.  The only way this would stop them from getting more downvotes is if users are purposely following their actions and looking to downvote their questions.  (How many times can you say you've downvoted the same user 10 times in a month? If you reach that limit frequently you might want to consider whether you're downvoting them for the wrong reasons.) If a question is bad it will be downvoted by other users regardless.  Imposing a limit for a specific user won't stop that.

Comment: In other words, your argument is hardly valid.  Imposing this kind of limit would rarely effect users who are not trying to deliberately abuse the voting system.

Comment: @Nathan noted, edited. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @tjw Not everywhere is like [so]'s C++ tag. There are some tags, and some other SE sites in which people who really know and will downvote a bad answer, ensuring they'll see it, is low. You're stopping them from being consistent with their indication of low quality, while the low-quality poster will continue.

Comment: If that is the case, very few people will see these posts to upvote them and encourage bad posts either... so again, not really a valid argument.

Comment: @tjw don't mix this with "pity upvotes". We **need** downvotes to show that the quality of the post is low. We shouldn't disallow those people to downvote bad posts just because it was the poster's 10th bad post.

Comment: I wasn't talking about "pity upvotes"... if the question has very little views it won't get very many upvotes or downvotes. It's as simple as that.

Comment: So, why stop the downvoter from saying *this is a bad question* just because the asker has a bad record of questions? Note that (no. of people ab-voting / no. of people voting) is a very small ratio.

Comment: It would not be stopping the downvoter because the asker has a bad record of questions. It would in fact be the complete opposite of that.  It would be stopping the downvoter from downvoting because their record of downvotes is questionable.

Comment: Yet, the very decision to ask the question earned @tjwrona1992 a full 11 down-votes. Why? Even if there is no legitimate way to limit this practice whole cloth, I feel the constant down-voting of the question is somewhat  disturbing. It is almost as if any questions relating to the caliber of ones reputation or the voting process, or who is voting and why, seems to be generally frowned upon as evidenced by down-votes on these type of inquiries.

Comment: @gracey downvotes here, and pretty much on any [tag:feature-request] on any meta, only indicate disagreement. Why shouldn't the 11th person say "I disagree with this idea"? It's their right.

Comment: Of course, but IMHO it just seems retributive because nearly every question I've seen that has a similar topic, in general,  just seems to automatically gain instant disapproval, and these are valid questions. People want to feel like they are being listened to, and if you feel you're being targeted in the first place, and then to simply ask results in a loss of 11 points to your reputation, I can see this chilling the will of others to ask these type questions.

Comment: Also, for many users, down-votes denote a bad question not just disagreement. And if that is the case, it should state that is the purpose (in the community "tour" ) for the act itself, rather than a measure of the quality of the question, as is the standard most elsewhere.

Comment: People coming in with relatively big changes or rate-limits should/must have evidence to back it up. This guy just came in with a request and said *It's just common sense.* No reason why this would be a good idea; rather, he tried to negate the arguments of the two answers. **And**, if people take downvotes personal, it's their problem. And if people don't look at the "Vote difference on meta page" on FAQ, it's again their problem.

Comment: Its funny how you tell me I have no evidence when neither answer has any hard evidence either...  Realistically without access to internal SE voting statistics that may not even exist... and if they do exist I don't even know if moderators have access to them, so realistically there is no way to prove either side of the argument with "hard evidence."  Go ahead and argue with me, you have the right to disagree, but don't bash on me for not having any evidence when you fail to provide any statistics in your posts either.

Comment: @tjw as I said before, it's **your** job to convince us that it'd be useful; not the other way around. We've given an argument against, and all you said was *it's just common sense*. It's over now, get over it. It isn't happening.

Comment: I'm already aware it's not happening... Unfortunately there's too many stubborn people like you who downvote anything that mentions the word "downvote." (It's kind of funny and contradictory if you think about it)... But if you're going to tell me that I have no right to post without providing hard evidence, what right do you have to argue without providing evidence yourself? ...None.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good boy; by starting to call me names; you just demonstrated that "I don't like to participate in this discussion constructively anymore." So I won't respond after this. || Do you think the devs have time to implement every single feature-request? There are a lot of FRs that actually have merits and were declined. TL;DR: You're proposing a limit on the voter because another poster posts a lot of low-quality posts in a short time. That rate-limit doesn't make sense.

Comment: @gracey209, questions similar to this one receive downvotes because users have said repeatedly that it's an idea they disagree with. When posting something today that people disliked a week or month ago, one shouldn't be surprised with a similar voting pattern. They are certainly being listened today. This question got two answers and many comments. Unfortunately for the OP, they disagreed with the OP's proposal. [1/2]

Comment: Downvotes on Meta indicate disagreement, not "bad question". That is the culture of Meta. Not realizing that is a failure to understand the culture of the site. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta specifically the "Voting is Different" section. [2/2]

Comment: Calling someone stubborn is not name calling, but have a nice day in your make believe world where everyone follows the rules and all bad people are caught by automated systems that are definitely robust enough to catch everyone. :)

Comment: Also don't go around thinking you have the authority to say "So it's a no." You might want to leave things like that to the moderators who earned that right. Ultimately it's up to the community, not you.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the reasons given in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263557/162102), if your limit on downvotes in a time period is lower than the limit of posts someone can make, then you're handing people who consistently post low-quality material a "get out of consequences free" card.  Most people downvote rarely or not at all, and I want those who *do* downvote to continue providing that indicator of quality.

If targeted voting is happening, moderators and community managers have ways to detect and investigate that.

Finally, for parity you would need to also limit *upvotes*, because for every grouch with a vendetta there are probably a dozen fans of someone else.  Before you say "yes, upvotes too, then", consider what such a limit would do to the economy of a site, particularly ones still trying to get off the ground.

Comment: Again... realistically why would a person reach that limit when voting on a single other person?  In 99% of all cases either serial downvoting or serial upvoting would be a factor.

Comment: @tjw you're making assumptions. Please show stats that support "In 99% of all cases either serial downvoting or serial upvoting would be a factor."

Comment: Obviously I don't have those statistics... No one does. it's just common sense.

Comment: Show me your statistics that lead you to believe this would prevent a large number of **valid** downvotes from happening.

Comment: Your common sense is lying to you because you're frustrated by possible serial voting targeted at you. Just custom-flag your question, and ask a mod to take a look at it. And, we're not here to prove anything; you have to prove this is useful and doesn't counter with the banning mechanism.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 I have seen users post dozens of junk questions (sometimes junk answers too) in just a few days.  Auto-bans will stop the bleeding until we can educate them (if they're receptive) or they go away, but *those bans require downvotes*.  You want somebody to be able to make 50 posts in a month (I think that's the current limit) but you don't want the community to be able to regulate those posts.  No.  If you have some evidence please offer it.  (The burden of proof should be on the one seeking a change.)

Comment: I do want the community to regulate their posts.  Regulating posts is a community effort and cannot be done by a single person.  If multiple people think the post is bad it will get the downvotes it deserves.  If someone is frequently reaching the post limit of 50 every month that is good reason for a moderator to personally look into the quality of their posts.

Comment: example when users post junk at a damaging rate: [Fix serial downvoting reversal to not apply to users spamming site front page with bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199418/165773)

Comment: That's already broken. Changing this would actually probably help because it would trigger less automatic resets