# Please extend the automatic slow-down system to also apply to answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, post-ban, rate-limiting

A couple of years ago [a rolling rate limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide) was added that limited the number of new questions a brand new user could ask, and adjusted that limit based on the feedback they were getting. It was there to reduce the ability for new users to crash and burn via a series of terrible questions and get themselves into more permanent trouble, similar to a learner driver. That system seems to be working well for questions.

**Please extend this system to also cover answers.** It currently does not, and on the site I moderate ([RPG Stack Exchange](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)) users crash and burn via a string of bad answers once a month or so — often by answering the categories of questions that are hard to answer well, but they don't know that yet since they're new. If the slowdown feature applied to answers it'd limit the damage they do to themselves before hitting a permanent answer ban, and limit the frustration and give us an opportunity to show a new user the ropes before they get into serious trouble.

I don't see much crashing and burning via questions on RPG.SE, so the rolling rate limit seems to be working well, and I'd like to see that same change occur for answers.

Comment: strongly related: [Fix serial downvoting reversal to not apply to users spamming site front page with bad answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199418/165773). Not only brainless system lets them pollute the site, but it even reverses totally legitimate, [content-based](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199418/fix-serial-downvoting-to-not-apply-to-users-spamming-bad-answers#comment633472_199418) votes as serial ones. Very frustrating